# JestJs TestSuite is not creating a Database using a mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I am using jestjs for the first time and have the following issue. Please see the ISSUE tag.

**Below is the code**

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { app } = require('../src/app');
const { User } = require('../src/models/user');

const userOne = {
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 45,
  email: 'Mike1@gmail.com',
  password: '5689@wWe',
};

beforeEach(async () => {
  await User.deleteMany();
  await new User(userOne).save();
});

// afterEach(() => {
//   console.log('after Each');
// });

test('Should signup a new user', async () => {
  await request(app).post('/users').send(userOne).expect(201);
});

test('Should signin a user', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post('/users/login')
    .send({
      email: userOne.email,
      password: userOne.password,
    })
    .expect(200);
});

test('Should not login non existent user', async () => {
  await request(app)
    .post('/users/login')
    .send({
      email: userOne.email,
      password: '5689@wWe1',
    })
    .expect(400);
});
```

**Here is my package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "mongodb-promises",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env jest --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "author": "Nagendra Babu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.16",
    "mongoose-auto-increment": "^5.0.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "sharp": "^0.25.3",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

**test.env file**

```
MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api-test-db
```

**dev.env file**

```
MONGODB_CONNECTION=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api
```

**DB Image**
[My current database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZZKl.png)

**Issue**
1. When I am running the above the test suite, jestjs is not creating a new database in the mongodb.
Please help me out am I doing something wrong.

**Test Result in the Terminal when npm run test is ran**
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
 FAIL  tests/user.test.js
  × Should signup a new user (187 ms)
  √ Should signin a user (66 ms)
  √ Should not login non existent user (51 ms)

● Should signup a new user

```
expected 201 "Created", got 400 "Bad Request"

  at Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:268:12)
  at Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:283:11)
  at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:173:18)
  at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.398 s, estimated 3 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Comment: how are you connecting to the database?

Comment: I am connecting to database in another file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  }
);

module.exports = { mongoose, validator};
```

Comment: It is working fine when I am running

npm run dev

failing when I am running

npm run test

Answer (score 0):

Are you also following Mead's lectures ? 
You can actually check the error by going on to the endpoint like `/users` and logging the error output.
The **'Bad Request'** here is a **data validation error**.

Here is my code for reference :

```
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../src/app')
const User = require('../src/models/user')

const userOne = {
    name: 'Hello1',
    email: 'Hello@example.com',
    password: 'HelloWorld1'
}

beforeEach(async()=>{
    await User.deleteMany()
    await new User(userOne).save()
})

test('Should sign up a new user', async()=>{
    await request(app).post('/users').send({
        name: 'Abcdef',
        email: 'abcde@example.com',
        password: 'HelloWorld1'
    }).expect(201)
})

test('Should Login Existing User', async()=>{
    await request(app).post('/users/login').send({
        email: userOne.email,
        password: userOne.password
    }).expect(200)
})

test('Should not login nonexistant User', async()=>{
    await request(app).post('/users/login').send({
        email: userOne.email,
        password: '567abcd'
    }).expect(400)
})
```